# how to pass an Action<in T> with a derived class as the Action parameter?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
class BaseClass {}
class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}
```

I want to write a function that can accept an Action with a BaseClass parameter.  The function will create an object of the specified type and pass it to the Action.

```
void MyFunction(Type type, Action<BaseClass> DoAction)
{
  BaseClass obj = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
  DoAction(obj);
}
```

I want to pass in AnotherFunction whose parameter is a DerivedClass:

```
void AnotherFunction(DerivedClass x)
{
}
```

How should I call MyFunction?  The following is invalid due to the AnotherFunction argument:

```
MyFunction(typeof(DerivedClass), AnotherFunction);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If at all possible, try to use generics instead:

```
void MyFunction<T>(Action<T> DoAction) where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    DoAction(new T());
}
```

Then you can just write:

```
MyFunction<DerivedClass>(AnotherFunction);
```

This will:

- Do compile time checking to ensure the type you use is `BaseClass` or a type deriving from it.  You won't get runtime errors because the type doesn't extend `BaseClass`.
- Do compile time checking to ensure that the type has a parameterless constructor, rather than throwing an exception at runtime if one doesn't exist.
- Do compile time checking to ensure that the method provided for the `Action` accepts a parameter appropriate for the type used, instead of throwing an exception at runtime if the type isn't appropriate.

Comment: I think MyFunction(AnotherFunction) won't compile without explicitly specifying generic argument type.

Comment: @jure -- Right.  Trying to work through this now.  I'm still new to some parts of C#